# Allocate custom memory

Tags: objective-c

how can I allocate custom memory?

Comment: c'mon dude, at least try and ask a clear question....

Answer (score 1):

By using `[[obj alloc] init]`, where `obj` is the object you would like to allocate memory for and initialize.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by custom memory? Just a block of memory?

Simply use C memory allocation:

```
char *myMemory = malloc(1000); // allocates 1,000 bytes of "custom" memory
```